# How to add font-family style to Html Email Template

Tags: css, email, templates, fonts

Hey I have an issue with adding Font Style to my confirmation Template which I send to my clients Email after the order is done.
I know inline css works just fine with html email template but I'm trying to add Heebo font-family from google and I can load it in the head tag which won't work on gmail and hotmail.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Heebo" rel="stylesheet"></head>
```

right now this is my head.
but It won't work in gmail or hotmail as I said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

quick answer. You cant do it.

gmail, hotmail, outlook, etc blocks external fonts for security reasons.

its because of this that mails are normaly build with images and not 100% text.

if you dont want to use images, you have to use safe fonts (fonts that exist in all operating systems).

good luck

Answer (score 0):

I include it this way.  You can get this from Google web fonts.
This works on Outlook (IOS), Apple Mail, iPad, iPhone.  The rest do not support web fonts.  So you should have a fallback font that will work as default.

Ideally your email should be a hybrid of live-text/image based.
Being 100% image based now is kinda out-dated since you cant see anything when browser auto hides images and cant search for anything or highlight any useful info like product names.

useful article covering this:  https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-fonts

```
@media screen {
 /* latin-ext */
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Raleway'), local('Raleway-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v12/1Ptug8zYS_SKggPNyCMIT4ttDfCmxA.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
  }
  /* latin */
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Raleway'), local('Raleway-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v12/1Ptug8zYS_SKggPNyC0IT4ttDfA.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
  }
  /* latin-ext */
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    src: local('Raleway Bold'), local('Raleway-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v12/1Ptrg8zYS_SKggPNwJYtWqhPANqczVsq4A.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
  }
  /* latin */
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    src: local('Raleway Bold'), local('Raleway-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v12/1Ptrg8zYS_SKggPNwJYtWqZPANqczVs.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding font for Email template it is taking on Arial from system font no use of adding Google fonts cdn link